# pdf header footer append

Tags: php, pdf

I want to change pdf files. I will erase header and footer from pdf, but more important than that I want to write pane number, etc. to the pages.

I saw a pdf tool, that just renders page as jpg and you manuplate pdf in that way. But I want users to select text from pdf. I dont want to disturb internals of orginal pdf much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to get something like [PDFlib](http://pdflib.com). It can load up pre-generated PDFs and add arbitrary content (new pages, new content on existing pages, etc...). However, the licensing for it is fairly steep.

However, since a PDF is just a Postscript file, you CAN go inside it and manipulate the postscript code to make some of the changes you want, as long as the PDF isn't secured with a password (which means it'd be encrypted).

Comment: afaik PDFlib PDi (import) only imports as an image. I'll check that in more detail. thank you for clues.

Comment: Naw, I've used PDi extensively. It'll import entire PDF documents page-by-page, letting you superimpose new content.